# React how to prevent reverse map function getting called on every state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some handleClick and onHover functions which functions as expected - the problem is that the `const portItems` is also getting called every time a setState is called - which results in the portItems element getting reversed all the time / and i'm guessing it's ineffective for performance to unnecessarily run the same function over and over again.

The portItems does pass a click event to the PortItem

I cant figure out how to fix this behavior?

```
import React, { Component} from 'react'
import portData from "./portData"
import PortItem from "./portItem"
import ArrowRH from "../../files/images/ArrowLeftHighlight.svg"
import ArrowR from "../../files/images/ArrowLeft.svg"

class PortfolioPage extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state ={
            portLength: 8,
            skipLenght: 4,
            startPort: 0,
            arrowside: null
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
        this.oneHover = this.onHover.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick(id) {
        if(this.state.arrowside !== null){
            if(this.state.arrowside === 'right' && this.state.startPort + this.state.portLength < portData.length ){
                this.setState((prevState) => ({
                    startPort: prevState.startPort +this.state.skipLenght
                }));
            }
        } 
    }

    onHover(side, sit) {
        if(sit === "enter"){
            this.setState({arrowside: side})
        } else this.setState({arrowside: null})
    }

    render(){
        const portItems = portData.reverse().map(item => <PortItem key={item.id} pitem={item} click={this.handleClick}/>)

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="portfolio-container">
                    <div className="portfolio-item-container">
                        {portItems.slice(this.state.startPort, this.state.startPort + this.state.portLength)}
                    </div>
                    <div className="arrow-container">
                        <div 
                        className="arrow" 
                        id="ArrowRight"
                        onMouseEnter={()=>this.onHover("right", "enter")}
                        onMouseLeave={()=>this.onHover("right", "leave")}
                        onClick={this.handleClick}
                        >
                            <img src={ArrowR} alt="Arrow Right" className={this.state.arrowside === "right" ? null : "active"}/>
                            <img src={ArrowRH} alt="Arrow Right Highlighted" className={this.state.arrowside === "right" ? "active" : null}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PortfolioPage
```

Comment: Assuming `portData` is sort of static array, you can `reverse` it once even outside the component.

Comment: It's a static array yes. But if i `reverse()` `portData` the ID's in `portData` will be reversed to their place in the `portData` array - that's why i need to `Reverse` the the `portItems` array

Comment: `reverse` twice? I'm not sure why..

Comment: No sorry, i spelled it wrongly - by removing the `reverse()` part from the const, and adding the `portItems.reverse()` underneath it. 
`const portItems = portData.map(item => <PortItem key={item.id} pitem={item} click={this.handleClick}/>) 
portItems.reverse()`

Comment: So, are you doing it outside of `PortfolioPage` component? Or still in the `render`?

Comment: Still in the `render`. `portItems.reverse()` gets run right underneath `const portItems` - i don't know why that works though